# How can I convince Python to import a class from a submodule when you import the package?

Tags: python

Example: `mypkg/submodule.py` with class `MyClass` inside.

I want to be able to do:

```
import mypkg
obj = MyClass()
```

What I need to do in order to make this work with default import?

I note that `from pkg import *` and `import pkg.submodule` works are working but I want to change the behaviour of the **default import**.

This is clearly related to `__init__.py` and `__all__`.

Comment: How I would hate if this were possible!  Nobody could tell where `MyClass` popped up from.  It is bad enough that `from pkg import *` exists.  (Well, the latter is quite handy for interactive use.)

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that normally (I guess with some crazy hacks it could be possible). You either have:

```
from mypkg.submodule import MyClass
```

Or if you setup `__init__.py` in the package appropriately, you could have:

```
from mypkg import MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, a simple python import will only add the module to the current namespace.

Now there are 3 alternatives for importing `MyClass`:

```
# mypkg/__init__.py
from submodule import MyClass
__all__ = ["MyClass"]

# mypkg/submodule.py
def MyClass(obj):
    pass

# test-usage.py
import mypkg
mypkg.MyClass()

# test-usage-2.py
from mypkg import MyClass
MyClass()

# test-usage-3.py
from mypkg import *
MyClass()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Does this answer your question?